# Dump binary file contents in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, bash, jq, binaryfiles

I have a binary file that I would like to pack as a JSON array like so:

```
{
  "content": [0, 23, 45,...]
}
```

Right now I dump the file using hexdump into a separate file (to print as unsigned u8's with commas)and manually paste those contents in the array:

```
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%u," foo.bin > foo_arr
```

Looking for a better way to achieve this preferably over the command line (jq, standard *nix tools), JavaScript could work as well but I'd rather avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option:

```sh
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%u\n"' foo.bin | jq -s '{content: .}'
```

Here, I use `jq`'s `-s` flag ("slurp") to read in all the lines of stdin as a single array, then simply use that array as the value of `content`.

For example:

```sh
$ python -c 'open("foo.bin", "wb").write(b"abc")'
$ hexdump -ve '1/1 "%u\n"' foo.bin | jq -s '{content: .}'
{
  "content": [
    97,
    98,
    99
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`:

```sh
$ printf "\x00\x17\x2d" > foo.bin
$ perl -0777 -nE '@bytes = map { ord } split //, $_;
                  $" = ","; # Delimiter when inserting an array into a string
                  say qq/{"content":[@bytes]}/' foo.bin
{"content":[0,23,45]}
```

Reads the entire file at once (`-O777 -n`) and splits it into an array of bytes, and then outputs the JSON with those byte values.

Comment: `perl -0777pe'@b = join ",", unpack "C*", $_; $_ = qq/{"content":[@b]}/'` (Avoids forward-incompatible `-E` and unneeded `$"` change.)

Answer (score 0):

`jq` can read raw input using `-R` (or `--raw-input`) and convert it to its codepoint numbers using the `explode` [builtin](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions):

```sh
jq -Rs '{content: explode}' foo.bin
```

If the binary file is not too large, you can also read it into a variable using `--arg` and then apply `explode` on that.

```sh
jq -n --arg bin "$(cat foo.bin)" '{content: $bin | explode}'
```

Note: `jq` operates on Unicode codepoints, whereas your current `hexdump` approach translates single byte counts, so the results may differ to this regard.